# Eloqua form has `<eloqua />` tags inside input values

Tags: eloqua

Eloqua is generating forms:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/6dce8530a881a3c5795e822ffefe508b?editors=1000

But the output html looks like this:

```
<input value="<eloqua type='emailfield' syntax='LastName' />" class="field-size-top-large"  />
```

I assumed that the value attribute was something that was then going to be replaced by some Eloqua JavaScript, but when I view it on the page with JavaScript, sure enough its still there:

[image]

How can I remove these tags? Is this a bug with Eloqua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to remove these. The `<eloqua />` tags are inside the value field like that because they are used on Eloqua **hosted** pages – so for instance if the marketing team are creating a landing or targeted page inside of Eloqua, or a page that is linked to from an Eloqua email. They only work on these Eloqua pages, not in self hosted forms.

If you are going to self host these forms (for example on your own website), here are the steps you can take to remove the tags:

1. Click the field

[image]

2. Click on the merge settings button

[image]

3. Select **None**

[image]

4. Note that the yellow disappears

[image]

5. Note that there is no longer a predefined value in the field

[image]